# OpenGL Geometry Shader Compilation Error OSX-Mavericks

Tags: opengl, glsl, osx-mavericks, geometry-shader

I started with a working OpenGL program (with vertex and fragment shaders) that draws a single GL_POINT.  Then I attached a simple geometry shader that outputs two points given a single point as input:

```
#version 400

layout(points) in;
layout(points, max_vertices = 2) out;

void main() {

    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0.1, 0, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();


    EndPrimitive();
}
```

When I run my program I get the following compilation errors from GL:

```
Error Compiling Shader: ERROR: 0:4: Invalid use of layout 'points'
ERROR: 0:5: Invalid use of layout 'points'
ERROR: 0:9: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_Position'
ERROR: 0:9: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_in'
ERROR: 0:10: Call to undeclared function 'EmitVertex'
ERROR: 0:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_Position'
ERROR: 0:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_in'
ERROR: 0:13: Call to undeclared function 'EmitVertex'
ERROR: 0:16: Call to undeclared function 'EndPrimitive'
```

My System Specs:

> Mac OSX 10.9, Nvidia Geforce 750M, OpenGL 4.1 driver

I also tried defining the following in my geometry shader:

```
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4: enable
```

But my driver does not support the extension.  This shouldn't be needed though since geometry shaders are apart of core since 3.2 (source: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_shader#See_also)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you really trying to compile this as geomerty shader? Can you show your shader compilation code?

Answer (score 1):

#### First, do not use `#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4: enable`.

Geometry Shaders are ***core*** in GLSL 4.00. The EXT extension actually has some different behavior such as `gl_VerticesIn` rather than `gl_in.length ()` to determine the size of the input and the use of program parameters to set the input/output primitive types rather than a layout qualifier. Core profile implementations from Apple do not even support that extension.

#### Second, all of the errors you have listed point to one thing...

You are trying to create a ***fragment shader***. Make sure you use `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER` when you call `glCreateShader (...)`.